# Configuration and connections for Ardour using QJackCtl

Tags: sound, jack, audio-recording, ardour

After a couple changes no sound is coming in or out Ardour anymore, either through the USB interface nor through the laptop speakers.

The changes that I remember:

- moving Ubuntu between disks
- installing QjackCtr
- updating Ardour version from 4 to 5.8

Videos, MP3, Audacity work perfectly with both USB or speakers.

Can you help understand if it is either a matter of QjackCtr/Ardour configuration, or jack connections, or something else?

I am not yet fond of the elements listed in the QjackCtr and how to connect them.

Here the screenshots of the current QjackCtr connections...

1. ...before launching Ardour
   [image]
2. ...after launching Ardour (I changed some when trying to make Ardour sound)
   [image]

Some system info:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Memory 7.8 Gb
- Processor Intel Core i7 CPU Q 720 @ 1.60GHz × 8
- Ardour 5.8.0 (rev 5.8) Intel 32-bit
- USB Behringer U-control UCA200
- QjackCtl Version: 0.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given hints in the [Ardour forum](https://community.ardour.org/node/14577) , the answer was the setup on QjackCtr, in particular in the settings, the choice of the interface (changed "(default)" to the CODEC USB audio):
[image]
Now through the USB I can hear the Ardour metronome and record instruments.